# Postgres pg_hba.conf localhost confusion

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I've run into a scenario where an application couldn't see the database.  My `pg_hba.conf` file had the following:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Security aside, the application was telling me it couldn't see the database at all, while other clients could see it:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
```

I had to point my application to the public `IP` of that box, and add that in my `pg_hba.conf` for it to work.  Also, it was confused with `localhost`, as it apparently looked at the `IP6` route then the `IP4` route, both throwing an error:

```
Could not spawn process for application /var/www/pints: The application encountered the following error: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
```

Question: What is the best way to force this into using the `IP4` route, and to best use `IP4` resources to handle communications while on the same box?  `localhost` was blind, as was `127.0.0.1`, so I'm confused.  Cheers

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) you didn't change `listen_addresses` (or restart after that) 2) a firewall problem.

Comment: Very good point.  Of all those options, which would be best?  It's been working all this time without any change, so `listen_addresses` might be faulty perhaps.

Comment: https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/PostgreSQL/Install_PostgresQL_in_Ubuntu.md#access-postgresql-over-network